# Removing Data Type From Tuple When Printing In Scala

Tags: scala, tuples, println

I currently have two maps: -

```
mapBuffer = Map[String, ListBuffer[(Int, String, Float)]
personalMapBuffer = Map[mapBuffer, String]
```

The idea of what I'm trying to do is create a list of something, and then allow a user to create a personalised list which includes a comment, so they'd have their own list of maps.

I am simply trying to print information as everything is good from the above.

To print the Key from mapBuffer, I use: -

```
mapBuffer.foreach(line => println(line._1))
```

This returns: -

```
Sample String 1
Sample String 2
```

To print the same thing from personalMapBuffer, I am using: -

```
personalMapBuffer.foreach(line => println(line._1.map(_._1)))
```

However, this returns: -

```
List(Sample String 1)
List(Sample String 2)
```

I obviously would like it to just return "Sample String" and remove the List() aspect. I'm assuming this has something to do with the .map function, although this was the only way I could find to access a tuple within a tuple. Is there a simple way to remove the data type? I was hoping for something simple like: -

```
line._1.map(_._1).removeDataType
```

But obviously no such pre-function exists. I'm very new to Scala so this might be something extremely simple (which I hope it is haha) or it could be a bit more complex. Any help would be great.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

What you see if default `List.toString` behaviour. You build your own string with `mkString` operation :

```scala
val separator = ","
personalMapBuffer.foreach(line => println(line._1.map(_._1.mkString(separator))))
```

which will produce desired result of `Sample String 1` or `Sample String 1, Sample String 2` if there will be 2 strings.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks Ivan. I only ever return one so the need for the separator isn't required, however performing anything on the _._1 seems to remove the data type. I'll a response as well to clarify what I was meaning. Ironically though this is going to be a huge help in another aspect too haha.

Comment: "I only ever return one" - the thing is List type does not confirm it, if you so sure that you have only the one element, maybe it would be better to choose more precise type - have just a String then.

Answer (score 0):

I have found a way to get the result I was looking for, however I'm not sure if it's the best way.

The .map() method just returns a collection. You can see more info on that here:- https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/scala-map-method/

By using any sort of specific element finder at the end, I'm able to return only the element and not the data type. For example: -

```
line._1.map(_._1).head
```

As I was writing this Ivan Kurchenko replied above suggesting I use .mkString. This also works and looks a little bit better than .head in my mind.

```
line._1.map(_._1).mkString("")
```

Again, I'm not 100% if this is the most efficient way but if it is necessary for something, this way has worked for me for now.